# ESP32 micropython PWM measurement

Tags: esp32, micropython

I'm trying to control a servo with a PWM signal with an ESP32 with micropython. I cannot seem to get the servo to move and therefore would like to check my PWM signal.

I created a testing script to generate a PWM signal on GPIO32 and measure this back on GPIO36. I connected a jumper wire between 32 and 36 and I'm using the following code:

```py
"""Testing script"""
import machine
from machine import Pin, PWM
import utime

# PWM on pin 32
p_out = Pin(32, Pin.OUT)
pwm = PWM(p_out)
f = 500
pwm.freq(f)
dc = 512
pwm.duty(dc)

# Measure on pin 36
p_echo = Pin(36, Pin.IN)
while True:
    timeout_us = int(2 * 1 / f * 1e6)
    print(
        f"Trying to measure pulse length of {dc/1024*1 / f * 1e6} us with a timeout of {timeout_us} us"
    )
    print(f"Pulse length: {machine.time_pulse_us(p_echo,0,timeout_us)} us")
    utime.sleep_ms(100)
```

The only thing I get back is

```
Trying to measure pulse length of 1000.0 us with a timeout of 4000 us                                                                                 
Pulse length: -1 us
```

I'm obviously missing something here. The documentation says:

> machine.time_pulse_us(pin, pulse_level, timeout_us=1000000, /)
>
> Time a pulse on the given pin, and return the duration of the pulse in
> microseconds. The pulse_level argument should be 0 to time a low pulse
> or 1 to time a high pulse.
>
> If the current input value of the pin is different to pulse_level, the
> function first (*) waits until the pin input becomes equal to
> pulse_level, then (**) times the duration that the pin is equal to
> pulse_level. If the pin is already equal to pulse_level then timing
> starts straight away.
>
> The function will return -2 if there was timeout waiting for condition
> marked (*) above, and -1 if there was timeout during the main
> measurement, marked (**) above. The timeout is the same for both cases
> and given by timeout_us (which is in microseconds).

Seems like the timeout expired and nothing happened. I don't really have something else to verify that the PWM output is actually doing something like a scope.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, my firmware had a bug (v1.18), updating to esp32-ota-20220213-unstable-v1.18-128-g2ea21abae fixed the issue for me.